# Using django user authentication from another app on server

Tags: python, django, cookies

I'm trying to reuse my django authentication system to authorize another app running on another docker container on the same server.

```
def get_username_auth(request):
    # Return the username if authenticated, None if not.
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print('Checked authorization for user: request.user.get_username()')
        return HttpResponse(request.user.get_username())
    else:
        print('Returned user not authorized')
        return HttpResponse('NOT_AUTHORIZED')
```

Since the request is coming internally (via another docker container), I don't think the cookies are read by django and the user is not authorized.

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can use some token authentication or if it only internally, you can do it by IP address

Comment: my suggestion Better you can use RESTApi for this authentication , i think it will great,

Comment: I don't want the user to have to do any additional input (e.g. re-login), will that still work?

Comment: Your another app should handle this. Adding token into request header

Comment: The django app needs the `session_id` in order to figure out which user. Only the django app would have access to that cookie.

Comment: check [this token based auth.](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication)